# How to connect openWrt (Virtualbox) to wifi?

Tags: wifi, virtualbox, openwrt

I'm new user of `openWRT` I using a internet wifi in Ubuntu 16.04, I installed openWRT in VirtualBox, I tried to connect to internet but I failed, when I try to ping google.com I get this message **bad address google.com **

[image: screenshort ===> /etc/config/network]

Answer (score 1):

Just went through the same issue this morning. You have a good documentation in [OpenWrt wiki for configuring your OpenWrt network when running over VirtualBox](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/virtualbox). The information below is all taken from the wiki, but I can assure that is working for a Barrier Breaker running on top of Ubuntu 16.04. The process is as follows:

1. With your VM off, open the VirtualBox Network tab and make the following configurations:

> - Configure Adapter 1 to use NAT
> - Configure Adapter 2 to use Bridge Adapter 
>    + Select your host machine's interface from the menu (the one that appears by using
>   commands as `iwconfig` or `ifconfig`). 
>    + disable promiscuous
>   mode

These configurations refer to the following screens (my wireless interface has the name *wlx0022..*, yours may be different):

[image]

[image]

2. Power on your VM and edit `/etc/config/network`. Change the two interfaces that the [wiki](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/virtualbox) mentions (*wan* and *lan*) and put them as it is shown below. Your interfaces may have different names before the change (in my case, the *wan* interface was *wan6*).

Your `/etc/config/network` file should look like this:

```
config 'interface' 'wan'
              option 'proto' 'dhcp'
              option 'ifname' 'eth0'

 config 'interface' 'lan'
              #option type 'bridge'
              option ifname 'eth1'
              #option ip6assign '60'
```

Just do the changes you need to in order to have your `/etc/config/network` file as it is shown above, but leaving the other interfaces in the file unchanged (as they are).
Then reboot OpenWrt. After that I was able to connect and ping to any site.

Answer (score 0):

First,change your network connection in VirtualBox to Bridge Mode

```
Settings --> Network --> Adapter 1 --> Attached to --> Bridged Adapter
```

Second,modify */etc/config/network* in OpenWRT

```
config interface lan
    option ifname   eth0
    option type     bridge
    option proto    dhcp
```

Restart your network by this command :

```
 /etc/init.d/network restart
```

Note: make sure your host (Ubuntu 16.04) is connected to DHCP server.Then your OpenWRT-VirtualBox should get the IP address from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect WiFi manually by editing file,
you need to edit mainly 3 files.

1. /etc/config/network
2. /etc/config/wireless
3. /etc/config/firewall

--> I would suggest adding the following portion in your network config file(/etc/config/network).
(make sure you do not have any assigned section for the wifi in the network config file)

```
config interface 'wifi'
    option proto 'dhcp'
```

--> Also, you need to update the file (/etc/config/wireless)

```
config wifi-iface 'station1'
     option device 'radio0'
     option ifname 'wlan0'
     option mode 'sta'
     option network 'wifi'
     option disabled '0'
     option ssid 'name_of_the_wifi'
     option key 'password_of_the_wifi'
     option encryption 'encryption_of_wifi_generally_psk2'
```

in above setup `option network 'wifi'` "wifi" will be the name of the interface you defines in the /etc/config/network.[make sure if you have above section you edit the existing one. Do not add new section if you do not know what you are doing]

Here, replace "wlan0" with your wireless interface.

If you already have above section in wireless file,
you can also use uci commands as following,

```
uci set wireless.station1.ssid=name_of_wifi
uci set wireless.station1.key=password
uci set wireless.station1.encryption=psk2
uci commit wireless
wifi down; wifi
```

here, "station1" would be the name of the section.

--> In the /etc/config/firewall, find the `option zone` section where all the interface is defined, which looks like following

```
config zone
        option name             wan
        list   network          'wan'
        list   network          'wan6'
        option input            REJECT
        option output           ACCEPT
        option forward          REJECT
        option masq             0
        option mtu_fix          1
        option conntrack        1
```

and add

```
list network 'wwan'
```

Command to check Wifi Connectivity: `iwconfig`

Refer the following link:
https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/wireless

NOTE: PLEASE READ FROM OPENWRT FORUM OR GOOGLE BEFORE DOING ANYTHING
The Wrong configuration may break the OpenWRT connection